# Optimizing using scipy.optimize.differential_evolution

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, differential-evolution

I have a custom function which takes 3 parameters with values between 0 and 1. I want to optimize these parameters using [differential evolution in Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.differential_evolution.html). How do I pass the parameters of the function that needs to be optimized to the `differential_evolution` function? Please see the code snippet below of my custom function.

```
def per_Model(x,y,z):
...
   newLimit = x ** initialLimit
...
   if simValue < y:
      maxSim=np.argmin(simMatrix)
      ...
   else:
      ...

   newLoad = z ** rankOfLoad
   ...
   bestAccuracy = accuracy_score(actualData,predictedData)

   return -bestAccuracy
```

I want to initialize the parameters x, y and z with some random initial values and find out which combination of these parameters produce the best result. How would I do this?

Comment: Did you mean to write the "snippet" the way you did? Right now it adds zero information

Comment: I have just added a bit more to the code. Hope it might help. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to share the whole function here.

Comment: There are examples at the end of the documentation page you linked, which clearly illustrate how to use the function. I don't see any value in repeating that information here at SO. However, if there is anything specific you do not understand feel free to ask.

Comment: I saw the examples at the end of the documentation where it also mentions the arguments to the function should be in the form of a 1-D array. Does that mean that I have to supply my 3 parameters x,y,z as a 1-D array? Could you please demonstrate this using my custom function shown above?

Comment: Yes. You can unpack them if you need to in your function like: ```x_, y_, z_ = x```. Warning: the original vec is assumed to be called x. Please do some basic python-research first. The examples should be enough to get going. On the optimization-side, things are more complex and your function might behave weird as if's (like in your example) are often non-smooth. Optimization-tools are no silver-bullets. One has to take care!

Comment: Thank you @sascha. That was most helpful, I will give it a try.